# Update props value in child component in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

parent.vue

```
<template>
...
<div>{{ meet}} </div>
...
</template>
...
props: ["meet"]
```

child.vue

```
<template>
...
<meet :meet="showMeet(e.id)" /> 
</template>
...
props: ['meet'],
...
methods: {
   showMeet(id) {
      this.meet == 'abc';
   }
}
```

How do i update the value of the props to be used in child component

Comment: Can you please add little more information- `:meet="showMeet(e.id)"` are you passing method ? `this.meet == 'abc';` this is conditional statement not a value change

Comment: You can use either computed or watch property. But by default props values are reactive.

Comment: @Md.JahidulIslam is there any sample on using watch to update props value?

Comment: @Cristal Your sample does not really show clear parent-child relationship, please add more details?

Comment: @satyamPathak, By default props are reactive, if you update value from parent, value will be automatically updated. if you want to notice any changes then 

watch: { meet (val) {console.log('changed value', val; //any logic you want to do}}

Comment: @SatyamPathak I need to update value from child component to be used in child component

Answer (score 0):

You may need to re-render the child component again. As per my understanding so far, the same prop is present in both the child's and if you update it's value from one, then you want to update it in second too. Refer this

https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/